# getimagesize: failed to open stream error

Tags: php

I have that error message when I upload an image

```
Warning: getimagesize(C:\xampp\tmp\phpA563.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\dzmarket\admin\controllers\c_banners.php on line 61
```

my code is

```
        $file = $_FILES['image'];
        $allowedExt = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');
        $uploadsDirectory = 'resources/uploads/banners/';
        $maxSize = 4000000;
        $upload = new Upload($file, $allowedExt, $uploadsDirectory, $maxSize);
        $uploadFile = $upload->uploadFiles();
        $fileNames = $upload->getFilesName();
        $tmpname = $file['tmp_name'][0];
        $fileSize = getimagesize($tmpname);
```

and the print_r($file) gives me that

```
Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => 623211835.jpg ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/jpeg ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => C:\xampp\tmp\php9584.tmp ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 605275 ) )
```

I called the tmp_name correctly and I don't know where is the problem

Comment: The error message is answer. You can not use `tmp_name`. You should use the real file name and path. For example `$uploadsDirectory . $file['name'][0]`.

Comment: but I try to put a condition to the dimensions of the image before it uploaded that's why I used the temporary folder

Comment: I think you can't read client's folder file. Because php is run on the server. I think if you want, you can try to use `js` to do it, because js is execute on client. That just my opinion, I don't real do it.

Comment: ok I'll think about it, thank's for help

Comment: try this `$_FILES['image']['size'] `

Answer (score 3):

Call getimagesize() before you upload the file. For me, the $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] was removed after I had uploaded the file.

Comment: The file **must** be uploaded to the server for PHP to access it.